# How to delete all files except last 5 ordered by date in linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, file, sorting

I have folder with big amount of logs, extension is ".log".

```
2020.01.03.log
2020.01.04.log
2020.01.01.log
2020.01.02.log 
do_not_remove_1.txt
2020.01.06.log
2020.01.07.log 
do_not_remove_2.txt
2020.01.05.log
```

I need to sort them by date and delete all log files except recent 5 log files.
Also this folder contains other files, but log files are all with extension ".log", so i need to filter them, then sort, then remove all except recent 5.

i.e. i need to remove

```
2020.01.01.log
2020.01.02.log
```

from example above.

How to do this in linux bash?

Comment: Maybe something like `find directory/ -name "*.log" -type f -print0 | sort -z | head -z -n -5 | xargs -0 rm` (Which is probably more robust at dealing with funny characters in filenames than you need here, but no kill like overkill)

Answer (score 3):

Start with this:

```
ls -tr | head -n -5
```

This gives you a listing of all files except the newest 5. Now pipe this into `xargs`:

```
ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs rm -f
```

This is not a complete solution yet, it will likely cause problems with filenames that contain unusual characters. But you can start working from there.